# Pivoting pandas table with mixed value types by ID and time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table `df` of the kind (not actual table) with mixed types for the values:

```
      ID    |        Time        |  Category  |  Value
ix   ----------------------------------------------------
0     457   |  2010-09-04 15:00  |  Name      | 'Foo'
1     542   |  2010-09-04 15:00  |  Name      | 'Bar'
2     542   |  2010-09-04 15:00  |  Sub       |  0.2
3     542   |  2010-09-04 15:00  |  Age       |  18
4     457   |  2010-09-04 15:40  |  Sub       |  0.7
5     457   |  2010-09-04 15:40  |  Age       |  20
```

Now I want to convert this table into `cat_df` such that each category is its own column with the value as the rows and it is indexed by first the ID and then the time within a particular ID such that:

```
      ID    |        Time        |  Name  |  Sub  | Age
ix   ----------------------------------------------------
0     457   |  2010-09-04 15:00  | 'Foo'  |  -    |  -
1     457   |  2010-09-04 15:40  |   -    |  0.7  | 20
2     542   |  2010-09-04 15:00  | 'Bar'  |  0.2  | 18
```

Dash denotes `NA/NoneType`. I keep on getting duplicate errors whenever I use `df.pivot` with ID and Time as index. So I ran the following code:

```
mid_df = df.pivot(columns='Category', values='Value')
```

And I get the following table as a result for `mid_df`:

```
      Name    |   Sub    |  Age  
ix   ------------------------------ 
0     'Foo'   |    -     |  -
1     'Bar'   |    -     |  -
2       -     |    0.2   |  -
3       -     |    -     |  18
4       -     |    0.7   |  -
5       -     |    -     |  20
```

Which is fine, I guess? I can add ID and Time data through joining on `ix`. But I'd like to combine the rows by the Time for each ID. to get the final table above.

- So how do I convert `df` into `cat_df` directly while keeping ID and Time in mind?
- Or how do I combine the rows in `mid_df` to ensure least NA's for each time step?
- **Aggregating**: for both approaches, if I wanted to aggregate data by hour/data, how would I handle mixed data types for values? I'd like to average for numerical and select last for categorical
- Moreover, is there a way to determine which time period to aggregate by so as to ensure least NA's?

Answer (score 0):

For ID is not continue show up, you want to classify them into two group, then we need create a key(by using `cumsum` ) in order to help split, `first` will return the `first` not null value for each columns

```
s=pd.concat([df[['ID','Time']],df.pivot(columns='Category', values='Value')],axis=1)
s.groupby([s.ID,s.ID.diff().ne(0).cumsum()]).first()
Out[540]: 
         ID             Time  Age   Name  Sub
ID  ID                                       
457 1   457  2010-09-0415:00  NaN  'Foo'  NaN
    3   457  2010-09-0415:40   20    NaN  0.7
542 2   542  2010-09-0415:00   18  'Bar'  0.2
```